# How to add a folder under target directory to Java Build path Source In eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I want to add a generated folder under target directory to build path .

Can I do it in the same *pom.xml* after I generate the sources.
I tried like below. That didn't help.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>

    <configuration>
        <sourceExcludes>
        <!-- <sourceExclude>**/.svn/**</sourceExclude> -->
        </sourceExcludes>
        <sourceIncludes>
            <sourceInclude>target/generated-sources/xjc</sourceInclude>
        </sourceIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please help

Comment: why you need to add directory in the target folder under generated-sources?

Comment: I want to add them to the build path. Using maven i'm generating few classes, which will be generated in a folder under target. Right now i'm adding it to the build path manually. I wanted to do it as part of maven build itself.